# How can I access an ActiveRecord grandparent association through a parent association that has not yet been saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a situation where I would like access to an associated grandparent before the parent object is saved. I can think of several hacks, but I'm searching for a clean way to accomplish this. Take the following code as an illustration of my problem:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments
  has_many :custom_fields
  has_many :employees, :through => :departments
end
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :employees
end
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  delegate :company, :to => :department
end

company = Company.find(1)           # => <Company id: 1>
dept = company.departments.build    # => <Department id: nil, company_id: 1>
empl = dept.employees.build         # => <Employee id: nil, department_id: nil>

empl.company   # => Employee#company delegated to department.company, but department is nil
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.15. I understand what is happening here, and I understand why empl.department_id is nil; though I wish Rails held a direct reference to the prospective association prior to calling save, such that the last line could be delegated through the unsaved department object. Is there a clean work around?

UPDATE: I've tried this in Rails 4 as well, here is a console session:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > company = Company.find(1)
  Company Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Company id: 1, name: nil, created_at: "2013-10-24 03:36:11", updated_at: "2013-10-24 03:36:11"> 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > dept = company.departments.build
 => #<Department id: nil, name: nil, company_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > empl = dept.employees.build
 => #<Employee id: nil, name: nil, department_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p247 :004 > empl.company
RuntimeError: Employee#company delegated to department.company, but department is nil: #<Employee id: nil, name: nil, department_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0-p247 :005 > empl.department
 => nil
```

UPDATE 2: Here is a [test project on github](https://github.com/dissolved/activerecord_deep_obj_linking).

Comment: How very weird. I must try it out again later. It worked cheerfully enough last night. Check if `empl.association(:department) == Employee.new.association(:department)`...

Comment: The result of that expression is `false`. I see there is an instance variable `@target` on the association, which always seems to be `nil` (even for saved records). I don't know what `@target` is suppose to be, but it would make sense to me that it would contain the reference I'm desiring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please look into the `:inverse_of` option for [`belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) and [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many). This option will handle two-way assignments when building and fetching associated records in different cases.

From [Bi-directional associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Bi-directional+associations) for `ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods` in the docs:

> Specifying the `:inverse_of` option on associations lets you tell Active Record about inverse relationships and it will optimise object loading.

Comment: `inverse_of` is great for custom validations like `ActiveModel::EachValidator` on a nested form using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` when you need to access the parent of a `has_many` relation from the child but neither parent or child are saved.  without it, `child.parent` will be `nil`

Answer (score 1):

I don't love this solution, but this seems to solve the problem:

```
empl = dept.employees.build { |e| e.association(:department).target = dept}
```

It turns out you can pass a block to build, and ActiveRecord will yield to the block with the newly created record. Who knows what ActiveRecord weirdness such will bring. I'm leaving the question open for now to see if there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

After some console experimentation--you can just say `employee.department.company`, even if department is not yet saved. `department_id` may be nil, but the `department` association is there.

```
2.0.0-p195 :041 > c = Company.create 
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.9ms)  INSERT INTO "companies" DEFAULT VALUES
   (486.4ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Company id: 4, department: nil, custom_fields: nil> 
2.0.0-p195 :042 > d = c.departments.build
 => #<Department id: nil, company_id: 4, employee_id: nil> 
2.0.0-p195 :043 > e = d.employees.build
 => #<Employee id: nil, department_id: nil> 
2.0.0-p195 :044 > e.department === d
 => true 
2.0.0-p195 :045 > e.department.company === c
 => true
```

**Edit:** so, this didn't work on a different machine with another clean Rails 4 app. However, it still works on my laptop...also in a clean Rails 4 app. Let's try and figure out what's different!

```
e.method(:department)
=> #<Method: Employee(Employee::GeneratedFeatureMethods)#department> 

e.method(:department).source_location
=> ["/home/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-  
    4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb", 69]
```

Which leads us here:

```
def define_readers
  mixin.class_eval <<-CODE, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    def #{name}(*args)
      association(:#{name}).reader(*args)
    end
  CODE
end
```

No surprises really, this defines a method called `:department`

```
def department *args
  association(:department).reader(*args)
end
```

That call to `reader` just returns us the @target of the association if it is present, or tries to read it if it has an id at hand. In my case the `@target` is set to department `d`. To discover the point at which @target is set, we can intercept `target=` in `ActiveRecord::Associations::Association`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Associations::Association 
  alias :_target= :target=
  def target= t
    puts "#{caller} set the target!"
    _target = t
  end
end
```

Now when we call `d.employees.build` we get this...

```
"/home/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:112:in `set_inverse_instance'", 
"/home/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:376:in `add_to_target'",
"/home/neil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:114:in `build'"
```

`set_inverse_instance` is checking `invertible_for?(record)`, (where `record` is our new Employee instance.) This just calls `reflection.inverse_of`, and this has to return a truthy value in order for target to be set.

```
def inverse_of
  return unless inverse_name

  @inverse_of ||= klass.reflect_on_association inverse_name
end
```

So let's try that out...

```
2.0.0-p195 :055 > Employee.reflect_on_association :department
 => #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0xa881788 @macro=:belongs_to, @name=:department, @scope=nil, @options={}, @active_record=Employee(id: integer, department_id: integer), @plural_name="departments", @collection=false, @class_name="Department", @foreign_key="department_id">
```

That's non-nil, so @target will be set in my association when I call `d.employee.build`, so I can call `e.department`, and so on. So why is it non-nil here, but nil for you (and over on my other machine?) If I call `Employee.reflections`, I get the following:

```
> Employee.reflections
 => {:department=>#<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x9a04598 @macro=:belongs_to, @name=:department, @scope=nil, @options={}, @active_record=Employee(id: integer, department_id: integer), @plural_name="departments", @collection=false, @class_name="Department", @foreign_key="department_id">}
```

This is the product of the `belongs_to` method--it's got to be there if you look. So why (in your case) doesn't `set_inverse_instance` find it?

Comment: So, I changed that answer quite a bit after actually trying it out :)

Comment: Hmmm. Not for me. What version of Rails did you try that with?

Comment: That was with Rails 4. That said, there's no mention of this in the 'notable changes' for ActiveRecord in Rails 4, so it should be available in 3. I don't have a Rails 3 environment to hand or I'd give it a go. Take a look at what you get back from employee.association(:department) and see if the reference is buried in there.

Comment: I tried exactly what you show above in Rails 4 as well. e.department is nil, and e.department.company fails as you'd expect a nil would. Did you make any changes to the class definitions?

Comment: None--I literally just dropped them into the console as they are above and proceeded to execute those commands. (I had to guess at what the tables looked like but there's nothing special there.) I'll share my migrations when I'm at my laptop later, but really--they are as vanilla as it gets.