# Rails: How to set the grandparent value (association) in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How can I retrieve the data in the grandparent association.

Give the following models:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :rooms
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms, allow_destroy: true
  ...

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :schedule
  has_many :events
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
  ...

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  ...
```

I'd like to get `schedule.departure_date` in event.rb for using callback `before_save`.

**event.rb**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  before_save :assign_date

  private

    def assign_date
      self.from = DateTime.new(schedule.departure_date.year, schedule.departure_date.month, schedule.departure_date.day, from.hour, from.min)
    end
```

**schema.rb**

```
create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.date     "departure_date"
  ...

create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "schedule_id"
  ...

create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.time     "from"
  t.integer  "room_id"
  ...
```

When I try to execute this code, the following error appeared.

**development.log**

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `schedule' for #<Event:0x000000058bdd28>):
  app/models/event.rb:15:in `assign_date'
  app/controllers/schedules_controller.rb:51:in `update'
```

**schedules_controller.erb**

```
  def update
    @schedule.room.maximum(:day)
    if @schedule.update(schedule_params)
      flash[:success] = "Schedule updated!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

...

  private

    def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(:title, :departure_date, rooms_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :room, :day, events_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :from, :to, :title, :detail]])
    end
```

I use `simple_nested_form_for` and `simple_fields_for` in my view.

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to get `schedule.departure_date` in the `event.rb`.

Comment: I think its a typo you should use Schedule instead of schedule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion regarding a similar problem here: I think the second answer might be useful for you. [belongs_to through associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021322/belongs-to-through-associations)

The answerer suggests using delegation to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Albin. I can set the data with using `has_one :schedule,  through: :room` in `event.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try joining the models as shown in this answer [Activerecord: find record by grandparent value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906910/activerecord-find-record-by-grandparent-value).

You can also try `inverse of` option [How can I access an ActiveRecord grandparent association through a parent association that has not yet been saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553008/how-can-i-access-an-activerecord-grandparent-association-through-a-parent-associ)